# Multiple core type mappings for the same field in elasticsearch (e.g. string and object)

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to create multiple core type mappings for a single field e.g. a field Qty which allows both long/string values or a field which allows both object/string values?

I'm using the mongodb river and once the field is indexed as an object, it throws a MapperParsingException for all other data that contain this field as a string?

I read here https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1166 that this is not possible, does it still hold true? 
I'm using v 0.19.8.

I've also tried setting ignore_conflicts : true in my mapping as per the example shown http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/128ath8kh1/some-mapping-confusions-to-resolve, but the data I was looking for was not pulled into elasticsearch from mongodb.

I also took a look at http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Getting-MapperParsingException-while-parsing-a-string-and-a-number-td3897986.html, but I dont have control over the schema (can't rename the field differently if different types are encountered)

I'd like to make sure that elasticsearch has all the documents that I have stored in mongodb. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create multiple core type mappings for a single field e.g. a field Qty which allows both long/string values or a field which allows both object/string values?

No, but you might want to see if you can leverage the [multifield type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/) to get where you're trying to go